# How can I install GLUT, GLUI, GLEW, and, GLFW so that I don't need to pull hairs every time I create a new project in VS?

Tags: visual-studio, glut, glfw, glew

I have solved the GL and GLUT part by installing NVidia CG toolkit. But, having continuous trouble with GLEW, GLFW, GL WTF W, etc.....

I want to install .h, .lib,and, .dll files related to GLUT, GLUI, GLEW, and, GLFW in such a location so that I don't need to pull my hairs every time I create a new project in Visual Studio 2003/2005/2008/2010/2012/20.......  .

I am using 64 bit Windows-7.

But, others are bothering and confusing me every time I create a new project.

Comment: It depends on what your "continuous trouble" is. It's hard to know how to solve a problem if you won't say what that problem is.

Comment: @NicolBolas, where to place these files so that I don't need to go to VS -> linker -> Input, etc....

Comment: @anonymous Did you manage to solve your issue?

Comment: @MarkoPopovic, Yes. I followed http://www.41post.com/5178/programming/opengl-configuring-glfw-and-glew-in-visual-cplusplus-express.             But, I don't like it.

Comment: @anonymous Can you specify what don't you like about it? What is the problem with the solution I've suggested? Exporting a project template and using it every time you create a new project should remove the need to configure project property pages every time you create it.

Comment: @MarkoPopovic, The solution I followed, keeps the libs in a specific folder in a drive. If I move the folder, the solution is likely to be not working.    Template Export doesn't work in case of VC++. I found the File->ExportTemplate as disabled. Also, there are confusions about the naming of libs. Some are xyz.lib and some are xyz32.lib but are situated in x64 folders.

Comment: @anonymous "Template Export doesn't work in case of VC++." I'm guessing that you are using an older version of VS. Check my updated answer for details on exporting templates on older VS versions and how to solve library directory issue.

Comment: @MarkoPopovic, I am using VS2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty project in which you will once setup once all necessary properties in:

- C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories
- Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories
- Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies
- All additional properties if any are required ...

Then, use File -> Export Template from the VS menu to export project template, so you can use it every time you are creating a new project. More information about project templates can be found here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/xkh1wxd8(v=vs.100).aspx

EDIT:

Create an environment variable that will hold the path to your directory which contains the necessary libraries and headers (for example, GL_LIBS). Then, when setting up properties of the project to be exported, use this variable value instead an absolute path (for example: `%GL_LIBS%\xyz_headers_dir`). This way, if you want to change the location of the libraries, the only thing necessary is to change the environment variable and it will work. This is also helpful in situations when several team members work on the same project and don't want to keep these files in the same location.

One more thing, since "Export template" does not work on VS2010 or older, you will have to do additional steps. In case you are using VS2010, it is only a small issue since there is a VS extension which you can use to export project templates:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/57320b20-34a2-42e4-b97e-e615c71aca24/

If you are using an even older version, then you will have to create a custom wizard which enables you to export a VC++ project template:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/96xz4cw2(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I just found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx   Is it helpful?

Comment: These are macros that are helpful for setting up paths and other project properties. However, they are predetermined so you cannot use them to point to directory of GL libraries. That's why I've suggested to use environmental variable, you use it the same way as these macros but you control to what it will point to and you only have one thing to change when moving directory of GL libraries.

Comment: If I put the GLxyz libs into the directory of my solution? Creating Env Var poses a problem when changing the machine.

Comment: If you are satisfied with placing libs in your solution folder, you can omit usage of env variable and use macros instead. I thought you did not want to do this but I was obviously mistaken. Now just use VS extension I've mentioned and export the templete after you've setup the project.

Answer (score 0):

I do not advise this at all, since if you want to build a project *without* these libraries, you'll still have them cluttering up your include paths. This can cause conflicts with other libraries if they happen to use the same include files as one of these. But if you insist...

Visual studio has default paths that every project gets. You can simply add the include and library paths of your choice to these paths. In older versions of Visual Studio, they live in <kbd>Tools</kbd>-><kbd>Options</kbd>-><kbd>Projects and Solutions</kbd>-><kbd>VC++ Directories</kbd> or something like that. In newer Visual Studio versions, they live in the <kbd>VC++ Directories</kbd> property page of the project/solutions property sheet.